# Last Step On Multi Step Form Unable To Submit On Rails When Associate Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I've created a multi step form, each step has a model, 'Shop' and 'Mattress'. I've associated the models, so 'Mattress' belongs to 'Shop'. The first step, 'Shop' submits and is visible on the index page, however the second step, 'Mattress' which belongs to 'Shop' does not show anywhere, at all and Rails is showing no error. I have attached 'shops_controller' and 'mattresses_controller'. Is there a problem in the create action in the 'mattresses_controller' with how I have associated it? The goal is whatever I have written in 'Shop' form to be associated with what's written in 'Mattress' form

```
class MattressesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_mattress, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /mattresses or /mattresses.json
  def index
    @mattresses = Mattress.all

  end

  # GET /mattresses/1 or /mattresses/1.json
  def show
    @mattress = Mattress.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /mattresses/new
  def new
    @mattress = Mattress.new
  end

  # GET /mattresses/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /mattresses or /mattresses.json
  def create
    @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
    @mattress = @shop.mattresses.new(mattress_params)


    if @mattress.save
      redirect_to mattresses_path(@mattress)
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end

  end

  # PATCH/PUT /mattresses/1 or /mattresses/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @mattress.update(mattress_params)
        format.html { redirect_to mattress_url(@mattress), notice: "Mattress was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @mattress }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @mattress.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /mattresses/1 or /mattresses/1.json
  def destroy
    @mattress.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to mattresses_url, notice: "Mattress was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_mattress
      @mattress = Mattress.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def mattress_params
      params.require(:mattress).permit(:shop_id)
    end
end
```

```
class ShopsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_shop, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /shops or /shops.json
  def index
    @shops = Shop.all
    @mattress = Mattress.all
  end

  # GET /shops/1 or /shops/1.json
  def show
    @mattress = Mattress.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /shops/new
  def new
    @shop = Shop.new
  end

  # GET /shops/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /shops or /shops.json
  def create
    @shop = Shop.create(shop_params)


      if @shop.save
        redirect_to new_mattress_path(@shop)
      end

  end

  # PATCH/PUT /shops/1 or /shops/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @shop.update(shop_params)
        format.html { redirect_to shop_url(@shop), notice: "Shop was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @shop }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @shop.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /shops/1 or /shops/1.json
  def destroy
    @shop.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to shops_url, notice: "Shop was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_shop
      @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def shop_params
      params.require(:shop).permit(:shop, :shop_id)
    end
end
```

```
<p style="color: green"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Mattresses</h1>


<div id="mattresses">
  <% @mattresses.each do |mattress| %>
    <%= render mattress %>
    <p>
      <%= link_to "Show this mattress", mattress %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
</div>

<%= link_to "New mattress", new_mattress_path %>
```

```
<%= form_with(model: mattress) do |form| %>
  <% if mattress.errors.any? %>
    <div style="color: red">
      <h2><%= pluralize(mattress.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this mattress from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% mattress.errors.each do |error| %>
          <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div>
    <%= form.label :shop_id, style: "display: block" %>
    <%= form.text_field :shop_id %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :shops
  resources :mattresses
  root 'shops#new'
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  # root "articles#index"
end
```

```
class Mattress < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shop
end
```

```
class Shop < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :mattresses
end
```

Comment: I have added it

Comment: I have also added routes

Comment: Thanks. It looks like you're expecting to pass in the shop for creation of the mattress. Can you take a look at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources particularly the bit about `shallow` for nesting your mattress under the shop

Comment: I see, so when I submit the 2nd step on the form, it doesn't redirect anywhere, it just refreshes the page and clears the text field, so does that mean it doesn't save?

Comment: I have added the models

Comment: I now get a 'NoMethodError' highlighting the first line of code in the mattress form

Answer (score 0):

Okay, rewriting to remove the nesting of mattresses within shops.

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  resources :shops
  resources :mattresses
end
```

This generates routes similar to the following:

```
       Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
        shops GET    /shops(.:format)               shops#index
              POST   /shops(.:format)               shops#create
     new_shop GET    /shops/new(.:format)           shops#new
    edit_shop GET    /shops/:id/edit(.:format)      shops#edit
         shop GET    /shops/:id(.:format)           shops#show
              PATCH  /shops/:id(.:format)           shops#update
              PUT    /shops/:id(.:format)           shops#update
              DELETE /shops/:id(.:format)           shops#destroy
   mattresses GET    /mattresses(.:format)          mattresses#index
              POST   /mattresses(.:format)          mattresses#create
 new_mattress GET    /mattresses/new(.:format)      mattresses#new
edit_mattress GET    /mattresses/:id/edit(.:format) mattresses#edit
     mattress GET    /mattresses/:id(.:format)      mattresses#show
              PATCH  /mattresses/:id(.:format)      mattresses#update
              PUT    /mattresses/:id(.:format)      mattresses#update
              DELETE /mattresses/:id(.:format)      mattresses#destroy
```

For completeness, my Shop model:

```
class Shop < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = :shop_id

  has_many :mattresses, inverse_of: :shop, primary_key: :shop_id, foreign_key: :shop_id
end
```

and my Mattress model:

```
class Mattress < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shop, inverse_of: :mattresses, foreign_key: :shop_id, primary_key: :shop_id
end
```

My updated Mattress Controller:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class MattressesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_mattress, only: %i[show edit update destroy]
  before_action :set_shops, only: %i[new show edit update]

  # GET /mattresses or /mattresses.json
  def index
    @shops = Shop.includes(:mattresses).joins(:mattresses)
    @mattresses = Mattress.includes(:shop)
  end

  # GET /mattresses/1 or /mattresses/1.json
  def show; end

  # GET /mattresses/new
  def new
    @mattress = Mattress.new
    @shops = Shop.all
  end

  # GET /mattresses/1/edit
  def edit; end

  # POST /mattresses or /mattresses.json
  def create
    @mattress = Mattress.new(mattress_params)

    if @mattress.save
      redirect_to mattresses_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /mattresses/1 or /mattresses/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @mattress.update(mattress_params)
        format.html { redirect_to mattresses_path, notice: 'Mattress was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @mattress }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @mattress.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /mattresses/1 or /mattresses/1.json
  def destroy
    @mattress.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to mattresses_path, notice: 'Mattress was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_shops
    @shops = Shop.all.order(:shop)
  end

  def set_mattress
    @mattress = Mattress.includes(:shop).find(params[:id])
  end

  # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
  def mattress_params
    params.require(:mattress).permit(:shop_id)
  end
end
```

My updated Shop Controller:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class ShopsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_shop, only: %i[show edit update destroy]

  # GET /shops or /shops.json
  def index
    @shops = Shop.includes(:mattresses)
    # @mattress = Mattress.all
  end

  # GET /shops/1 or /shops/1.json
  def show; end

  # GET /shops/new
  def new
    @shop = Shop.new
  end

  # GET /shops/1/edit
  def edit; end

  # POST /shops or /shops.json
  def create
    @shop = Shop.create(shop_params)

    if @shop.save
      redirect_to new_mattress_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /shops/1 or /shops/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @shop.update(shop_params)
        format.html { redirect_to shop_url(@shop), notice: 'Shop was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @shop }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @shop.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /shops/1 or /shops/1.json
  def destroy
    @shop.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to shops_url, notice: 'Shop was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_shop
    @shop = Shop.includes(:mattresses).find(params[:id])
  end

  # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
  def shop_params
    params.require(:shop).permit(:shop, :shop_id)
  end
end
```

My mattress "new" view now looks like:

```
= form_with(model: @mattress, url: @mattress) do |form|
  - if @mattress.errors.any?
    %div{ style: 'color: red' }
      %h2
        = pluralize(@mattress.errors.count, 'error')
        prohibited this mattress from being saved:
      %ul
        - @mattress.errors.each do |error|
          %li= error.full_message
  %div
    = form.label :shop_id, style: 'display: block'
    = form.collection_select :shop_id, @shops, :shop_id, :shop
  %div
    = form.submit
```

and my mattress "index" view looks like:

```
%table
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Mattress id
      %th Shop
  %tbody
    - @shops.each do |shop|
      - shop.mattresses.each do |mattress|
        %tr
          %td= mattress.id
          %td= shop.shop
```

does that make more sense to you?

Comment: The nesting really does matter on where you select your shop for your mattress, and/or if you want to view all mattresses, by shop, or if you want to see all mattresses regardless of shop

Comment: It's only showing shop_id on the index and show view page, not what I type in to the forms

Comment: I would like to to see all mattresses by shop

Comment: removed the nesting, modified my local copy to match the hints in your code in your version, and updated my answer.

Comment: In the mattress controllers create action, for some reason the 'else' block's being executed instead of 'if' block, so its rendering ':new'

Comment: So the mattress isn't being saved, I have added @mattress.save but still no luck

Comment: The following is displayed in the terminal - Shop Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."shop_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["shop_id", 0], ["LIMIT", 1]]

Comment: it works fine for me, but you need to have some shops created before you can create a mattress ... https://github.com/t12nslookup/bedshop